# Removing a directory using shutil module

Tags: python

I'm trying to remove a directory using python but I do not want to recursively remove the whole directory path in the process: i.e

/home/dir/dir/dirtoberemoved

So I don't want to remove anything at a higher level just the one directory and all its contents. I've been looking on stackoverflow to research this question and most answers have included using the shutil module which I am unfamiliar with, looking at the python documentation for the module it says 'Delete an entire directory tree'

If I do something like this:

```
    if os.path.exists("/home/dir/dir/dirtoberemoved");

        shutil.rmtree("/home/dir/dir/dirtoberemoved");
```

or

```
         shutil.rmtree("/dirtoberemoved");
```

Will the entire path be removed? If so is there any good way just to delete one non-empty directory in python without deleting higher level directories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the whole path *to* the directory to be removed. Only the last part of the path will be deleted, the `/home/dir/dir/` part will be untouched.

The deletion refers to any sub-directories *contained* within the named path, so if there is a `/home/dir/dir/dirtoberemoved/foo` sub-directory it'll be removed together with it's parent.

Comment: @SarahAddis: If the answer was helpful, remember that you can mark it as such by checking the big `V` mark underneath the answer scores. That'll indicate to future visitors an answer was working for you!

Comment: I did this but I need a 15 reputation! I did however click underneath "Yes" for "Was this post useful to you" - thanks again.

Comment: nope definitely logged on. I am a relatively new user and my rep is only 11!